# Flyout menu with custom button, XAMARIN FORMS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would ask if it is possible to make your own button to open the menu.
The point is that when making a shell flyout menu the button to open the side menu is at the top and I would need it at the bottom.
I will be glad if someone can help me, thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems that this can not be modiied in Shell application. If need to achieve that, you can have a try with [Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could help

```
<Shell ...
       FlyoutIcon="flyouticon.png">
    ...       
</Shell>
```

Comment: I don't think it will help me i need just button at the bottom [LikeThis](https://ctrlv.cz/h4ry)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a bool in mvvm:

```
<Shell ...
       FlyoutIsPresented="{Binding IsFlyoutOpen}">
</Shell>
```

Alternatively you can set the state directly in code behind with:

```
Shell.Current.FlyoutIsPresented = false;
```

For more information take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/flyout